# DevExpress Scheduler for ASP.NET MVC using Razor engine - New appoitment form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress, scheduler

I'm using DevExpress for ASP.NET MVC (using the Razor engine) and I wanted to build page which displays a Scheduler. There is no problem to display it but when I want to create a new appointment (right click on a date, then "New Appointment"), my webpage does not display a "New Appointment Form". Here's what I'm doing in order to display my Scheduler (I've followed this tutorial : [Scheduler control for ASP.NET MVC](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument11536) )

```
@Html.DevExpress().Scheduler(
settings => {
    settings.Name = "scheduler";
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "SchedulerPartial" };
    settings.EditAppointmentRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "EditAppointment" };
    settings.Storage.Appointments.Assign(AstellasHDJ.SchedulerDataHelper.DefaultAppointmentStorage);
    settings.Storage.Resources.Assign(AstellasHDJ.SchedulerDataHelper.DefaultResourceStorage);

    settings.OptionsCustomization.AllowAppointmentCreate = DevExpress.XtraScheduler.UsedAppointmentType.All;
    settings.OptionsCustomization.AllowAppointmentEdit = DevExpress.XtraScheduler.UsedAppointmentType.All;
    settings.OptionsCustomization.AllowAppointmentDelete = DevExpress.XtraScheduler.UsedAppointmentType.None;
    settings.Storage.EnableReminders = true;

    settings.ActiveViewType = SchedulerViewType.Timeline;
    settings.Start = new DateTime(2012, 4, 18);

}).Bind(Model.Appointments, Model.Resources).GetHtml()
```

Any idea guys?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `Render Partial` view which will hold your custom form. You can check the "DevExpress" demo using scheduler with custom form. Hope this helps.